# translating loop from Fortran to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, fortran

I'm currently translating code from Fortran to MATLAB manually, and I am unsure of how to translate part of it. (The entire code actually is a 2,000 line subroutine.) The code is below.

```
C  Has series crossed neckline?
120        neckext=x(trough(peaknum-1))+
 *              dydx*real((t-trough(peaknum-1)))


        if(x(t).lt.neckext) goto 130
C      NO.  Here if series has not crossed neckline, nor new trough found
C           Check to see if new trough has been found.
        t=t+1
        if(t.ge.lastobs) goto 900
        if(x(t).lt.min) then
              min=x(t)
              mindate=t
              end if
        troughid=min*(1.0+cutoff)
        if(x(t).ge.troughid) goto 150
        goto 120

C      YES. Here if series crossed neckline before new trough found
130         dblcount=0
      if(poscount.ge.1) then
          DO 132 i=1,poscount
           if((enterdt(i)-2.le.t).and.(t.le.enterdt(i)+2)) then
           dblcount=dblcount+1
           end if    
132          continue
           if(dblcount.ge.1) then
C                write(30,2583) t,Cutnum
2583            format('DoubleCounting episode occurred at ',I5,
 *             ' with Cutoff = ',F3.1)
            goto 150
          end if
       end if
```

My problem is with this part of the code:

```
        if(x(t).ge.troughid) goto 150
        goto 120
```

When I was translating this part in MATLAB, I was writing something like:

```
if x(t,:)>=troughid
    t=marker;
    minimum=x(t,:);
end
```

But I don't know what to do with the label 120. When I translate it, do I write that part again? Because from what I understand, when I go back to 120, the code will be running again. Thanks!

EDIT: As a response to Chris's question on what labels 150 and 900 do, I'll post them here.

```
150        t=marker
           min=x(t)
```

And this is for the label 900.

```
C  Last observation found.  This iteration finished.
900        continue
```

Comment: And they say `goto`s make code hard to follow !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It's true.  So true.  On the other hand, how many other languages have vast amounts of battle-hardened numerical code?  I suppose that's a tribute to both the utter simplicity of F66/F77 and forty years of graduate students shedding blood, dignity, and tears.

Comment: If you haven't done so, it's worth developing some comprehensive (and ideally automated) tests to make sure that your port actually reproduces the original behavior.   This kind of work is tedious and error-prone.  A good test suite can save you tremendous amounts of time and frustration, especially if this code is important to some greater and more complicated goal.

Comment: Try the online F77 to F90 converter at http://www.polyhedron.com/plusfortonline.php for some code snippets. It will help you unravel the `goto` statments.

Comment: Hi @ja72, I actually thought of breaking up the code into parts, and converting it in F90. But the thing is, the code is very much complicated that it might be difficult to splice it into parts. (Since I saw that plusfort only allows you to do it 100 lines at a time.)

Comment: @sfstewman What do you mean with testing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it should be clear by now, Matlab does not include any variant of a "goto" command.  The core Matlab command set appear to be designed around the "structured programming" philosophy.  (Which, if I remember my CS ancient history correctly, was the great debate prior to object oriented programming.)  Wikipedia has a decent [discussion of structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming).

In the dark days before structured programming, people used to be very excited about flow charts, since that was one of the easiest ways to visualized and understand a piece of code using a lot of `goto` statements (now usually referred to as spaghetti code).

I suspect that you will need to flowchart the entire subroutine, and then decide which control flow constructs can best be used to recreate your code.  If it is a relatively simple diagram, then you should be able to recreate the entire code with `if` statements or `case` statements, although a series of small helper functions may be more elegant.  If it has a more complex structure, then it may take a little more creativity to translate.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a flowchart of the entire subroutine, and I found that the structure is complex; the loops seem to go back and forth with each other. I am unsure how to code them, though.


Anyway, may I ask you the distinction between `if` and `case` statements? Intuitively, they seem the same.

Comment: In Matlab, a `case` statement is mostly shorthand for a series of `if ... elseif ... elseif ... else ... end` statement.  Generally easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks! Now, in the case where some loops might overlap with each other (since it was the case of the result of my flowcharting), what kind of tricks can I use to disentangle the overlap? When do I usually use `break`, `return`, and `continue`?

Comment: Personally, I never use `break` or `continue`.  I'm concerned that I will exit to an unexpected level.  `return` is for early exit from a function, which it doesn't sound like you are using.  As for untangling a spaghetti flowchart, I think that's beyond what I can reasonably do.  Some googling for structured programming flowchart yields a few instructionals on the topic, e.g. http://www.hancock.k12.ky.us/hchs/cisco/programming/pdf/0_619_16023_3_02_OP.pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much for that; it was much clearer than the guide that I found online!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the first half of your code, until after the `goto 120` in a `while` loop. You can then break out of this while loop when the condition `if(x(t) .lt. neckext)` is met. For example, the logic could look something like the following. Note that I have not tried to convert it all to MATLAB (that is your job!!) but hopefully it gets you started.

```
% Has series crossed neckline?
neckext = x(trough(peaknum-1)) + dydx*real((t-trough(peaknum-1)));

if (x(t) < neckext)
    % Code below `goto 120` here...

else
    while (x(t) >= neckext)
        % Code above `goto 120` here...
    end 
end

% `goto 150` code here?
```

I'm not quite sure if the above is what you need, since without the full code I have no idea what `goto 150` and `goto 900` are supposed to do to the program flow (apart from making it hard to follow).

Comment: Hi @Chris, it's actually a 2,000 line subroutine that I am translating. Anyway, I'll post what goto 150 and goto 900 do to the program flow.

    150        t=marker
               min=x(t)

    900        continue

Answer (score 0):

Almost all allowed `goto`'s in Fortran can be translated into MATLAB by using `while`/`break`/`continue` constructs. I have written a (unreleased) program to automatically remove `goto`'s from Fortran code, then I use my program, f2matlab, to translate the code to MATLAB/Octave.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove your email address. See [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61031/181221) and linked questions for some more information on why. On this site it is preferred that answers are self-contained, not of the form "send me an email and I can fix it for you". In the future you can mention your code but try to put a link to (say, to github) so that anyone reading this answer can follow the solution, even if you leave this site or change email address.