# Rainflow algorithm - Fortran conversion to Matlab

Tags: fortran, call, goto

I am trying to convert a Rainflow cycle counting algorithm which is in Fortran, which is a language I am not familiar with, into Matlab.

There is a ready made Rainflow I've downloaded for Matlab but that does not fit the requirements of my project so I'm trying to build one from scratch.

Here is the Fortran code:

```
INTEGER BUFFER (4096), INDEX, VALUE, RANGE, MEAN, X, Y
INDEX = 0
10 CONTINUE
   call 'get next peak/valley', VALUE
   INDEX = INDEX + 1
   BUFFER (INDEX) = VALUE
20 CONTINUE
   IF (INDEX.LT.3) THEN
           not enough points to form a cycle
           GOTO 10
   ELSE
           X = ABS (BUFFER(INDEX)  - BUFFER(INDEX - 1))
           Y = ABS (BUFFER(INDEX - 1)  - BUFFER(INDEX - 2))
           IF (X.GE.Y) THEN
c -- cycle has been closed
                RANGE = Y
                MEAN = (BUFFER(INDEX-1) + BUFFER(INDEX-2))/2
c -- remove the cycle
                INDEX = INDEX - 2
                BUFFER(INDEX) = BUFFER(INDEX+2)
c -- see if this value closes any more cycles
                GOTO 20
           ELSE
                GOTO 10
           END IF
END IF
```

I had downloaded f2matlab (a Fortran to Matlab converter) but it requires a Fortran compiler which I do not have.

The bits I don't really understand how I can convert are:

1. The `call 'get next…` line (is this an input()?)
2. The `BUFFER(4096)` etc (is this a bit large to be a matrix in matlab?)
3. The `GOTO/CONTINUE` structure.

What do they mean, in English (or Matlab)?

I have seen
[How to translate fortran goto state to matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491705/how-to-translate-fortran-goto-state-to-matlab)
and
[translating loop from Fortran to MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263927/translating-loop-from-fortran-to-matlab)
but they do not help me very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 call 'get next peak/valley', VALUE
```

isn't (currently) syntactically valid Fortran and I'm not sure whether any compiler of yore would have understood it either.  I guess that it means get a `VALUE` for use in the following bits of code.

```
INTEGER BUFFER (4096)
```

is a simple declaration that `BUFFER` is a vector of `4096` integers, nothing to scare Matlab in that volume of data.

Finally, `GOTO` is an unconditional jump and the number following it is the label of the line to jump to, so `GOTO 10` means *execute the line with label 10 next*.  It was fairly common in FORTRAN of the vintage you are showing us to jump to a `CONTINUE` statement which is, in this context, a no-operation, execution continues to the next line.

In another context, with `DO` loops `CONTINUE` would have marked the end of the block of code inside the scope of the loop and would have a subtly different effect.